# Show that $\alpha$ divides the determinant of a particular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, factoring

To illustrate my problem with a specific example, consider the matrix
$$D=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} a_{{1}}+\alpha&a_{{2}}&a_{{3}}
\\ a_{{1}}&a_{{2}}+\alpha&a_{{3}}
\\ b_{{1}}&b_{{2}}&b_{{3}}\end {array} \right] 
$$
then show that $\alpha$ divides $\det(D)$.

More generally, my problem is as follows. Given the $n\times n$ matrices
$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{a}^T\\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{a}^T\\
\mathbf{b}_1^T\\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{b}_k^T\\
\end{array}
\right)
\quad\mathrm{and}\quad C = \mathrm{diag}([\overbrace{\alpha,...,\alpha}^{\text{m times}},\overbrace{0,...,0}^{\text{k times}}])
$$
That is, $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ make the first $m$ rows of $A$ and $\mathbf{b}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ make up the last $k$ rows of $A$ while $C$ is the matrix with $\alpha$ on the first $m$ diagonal elements and $0$ elsewhere. Also the vectors $\mathbf{b}_i$ are linearly independent s.t. $A+C$ has full rank when $\alpha\ne 0$.

Then show that that $\alpha^{m-1}$ divides $\det(A+C)$. That is, show that $\det(A+C) = \alpha^{m-1} d$. I do not need to know $d$, I only need to prove that $\alpha^{m-1}$ is always a factor of $\det(A+C)$.

It suffices (for my purposes) to consider the case where $m=2$.

For my example above in $n=3$, Maple gives $\det(D)=\alpha\, \left( b_{{3}}\alpha+a_{{1}}b_{{3}}+b_{{3}}a_{{2}}-a_{{3}}b_{
{1}}-a_{{3}}b_{{2}} \right) 
$

Comment: Putting $\alpha=0$ makes the determinant $0$ so $\alpha$ is a factor (considering the determinant a polynomial in $\alpha$).

Comment: For values of $m>1$ we may differentiate the determinant with respect to $\alpha$ but there may be simpler way.

Comment: In the last part you write $\det A+B$ . Do you mean $\det A + C$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh of course! Good observation. That sounds like enough to conclude that $\alpha$ is a factor, which may suffice for my purposes actually. very nice

Comment: Yes I did @ancientmathematician, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps needed.

(1) Add all columns into column 1.

(2) Subtract row 1 from each of rows 2-m.

At the stage the (1,1) entry is $\alpha +\sum a_i$, and all entries in rows 2-m are zero, apart from those on the diagonal which are $\alpha$.

(3) Evaluate by expanding on rows 2-m first, this will provide the factor $\alpha^{m-1}$ as required.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you